# Send multiple values in one email through the Email app script

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, mailmerge

I wanna set up a google script that will, with a press of a button, send one email to each user on the list. I have already set up the button, but I need help with merging all the values for one user in one mail instead of sending multiple emails with one value to the same person.

For example:

[image: Table example]

I basically need Rose to get one email which will have these items listed one below another:

```
pens
printer
sketchpad
ink and toners
```

and so on.

This is the script I have so far and there's a HTML body of the email as well:

```
function myFunction() {
  var name = 0;
  var email = 1;
  var objects = 2
  var emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("body")
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var data = ws.getRange("A2:D" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();
  data.forEach(function(row){
    emailTemp.fn = row[name];
    emailTemp.site = row[objects];
    var htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();
    GmailApp.sendEmail(row[email], "No objects ordered", "Blabla",{htmlBody: htmlMessage})

  });
  
}
```

Comment: Please add the codee of the `body.html` (the code to be included should be a [mcve])

Answer (score 0):

### A simple way to do it is through obtaining a reduced array of unique names / emails

This can be done e.g. with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14438954/11599789) function:

```
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}
```

- Then you can loop through all unique values
- Find all the rows where they are contained
- Push the corresponding objects into an array
- Proceed the array in `"body.html"` as desired.

Sample:

```
var unique = ws.getRange("A2:A" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues().flat().filter(onlyUnique);
  unique.forEach(function(person){
    var row_objects =[];  
    var mail = "";
    data.forEach(function(row){
      if(row[name] == person){
        row_objects.push(row[objects]);
        mail = row[email];
      }
    });
    Logger.log(row_objects);
      emailTemp.fn = person;
    emailTemp.site = row_objects;
    var htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();
    GmailApp.sendEmail(mail, "No objects ordered", "Blabla",{htmlBody: htmlMessage})
  })
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, however, I get the following error when I try to run the script: **ReferenceError: onlyUnique is not defined (line 8, file "Code")** for the following line:

```var unique = ws.getRange("A2:A" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues().flat().filter(onlyUnique);```

Comment: Did you insert  the funciton definition into your script? That is `function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}` in addition to your already existing funciton `myFunction()`? You need to have both funcitons in your script.

Comment: Crap, I forgot. :D Sorry, total beginner here. Thank you for your help!